# Java If-Else in HackerRank, Is my code good or can I get better solution for the problem

Tags: java, if-statement, conditional-operator, nlp-question-answering, control-statements

**Problem Statement**

**Task**

Given an integer,n, perform the following conditional actions:

If n is odd, print Weird
If n is even and in the inclusive range of 2 to 5, print Not Weird
If n is even and in the inclusive range of 6 to 20, print Weird
If n is even and greater than 20, print Not Weird
Complete the stub code provided in your editor to print whether or not n is weird.

**Input Format**

A single line containing a positive integer,n.

**Constraints**

1<=n<=100

**Output Format**

Print Weird if the number is weird; otherwise, print Not Weird.

**Sample Input 0**

3

**Sample Output 0**

Weird

**Sample Input 1**

24

**Sample Output 1**

Not Weird

**Explanation**

Sample Case 0: n=3
n is odd and odd numbers are weird, so we print Weird.

Sample Case 1: n=24
n>20 and n  is even, so it isn't weird. Thus, we print Not Weird.

My solution to the problem.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.security.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Solution {



    private static final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int N = scanner.nextInt();
        scanner.skip("(\r\n|[\n\r\u2028\u2029\u0085])?");
        if(N%2==0){
            if(N>1){
                if(N<6){
                    System.out.println("Not Weird");
                }
                else if(N<21){
                    System.out.println("Weird");
                }
                else{
                    System.out.println("Not Weird");
                }
            }
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Weird");
        }

        scanner.close();
    }
}
```

Can I get suggestions regarding the solution. Thank You.

Comment: If the code works as intended, it might be better suited for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Redefining the requirements will give you a much shorter piece of code. Think about how the two "Not Weird" conditions are all part of the same check, and how `[6, 20]` contains the only difference in that domain

Comment: There's also plenty of well articulated explanations in the answers section of each problem on HackerRank. Sometimes there's a tab on the question itself too that explains different approaches, although there might be a paywall.

Comment: What's a "better solution" is the part of your question that would need to be refined. If it is to be evaluated in terms of ease of maintenance, I find yours pretty legible, and as such quite good : it reflects business rules, so it's quite easy to update if requirements were to change. As opposed to one-liners, for instance. And performancewise, no input value requires more than 4 tests ; one-liners wouldn't test less, I guess. Maybe create and use constants for strings, as they might change in bulk. My 20 cents.  Follow suggestions by @Turing85 and bdehmer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conditions should be merged: the result is `Weird` for any number in the range `6 <= n <= 20` OR n is odd, otherwise it is `Not Weird`:

```java
System.out.println((6 <= n && n <= 20 || n % 2 != 0) ? "Weird" : "Not Weird");
// or
System.out.println((5 < n && n < 21 || n % 2 != 0) ? "Weird" : "Not Weird");
```

Comment: Actually, I am getting wrong output for your code. Since it is a necessary condition for N to be even then only we can check for the range. Here is the problem link can you try and come with better code. https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/java-if-else/problem

Comment: You could have run a code with a typo, which I edited out.

Comment: Oh, yes thank you. Now I got the correct answer. Previously I wrote this System.out.println((5<n&&n<21||n%2==0)?"Weird":"Not Weird");

Comment: System.out.println((6 <= n && n <= 20 || n % 2 != 0) ? "Weird" : "Not Weird"); so you have combined odd part and inclusive range of 6 and 20. Another one question is it good to use <=20 or <21. Which is better?

Comment: `< 21` is shorter, other than that there's no difference for integer numbers

Answer (score 0):

```
 if (~N % 2 == 0 || N <= 20 && N >= 6) {
   System.out.println("Weird");
} else if (N % 2 == 0 && N > 20 || (N >= 2 && 5 <= N)) {
   System.out.println("not Weird");
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.